# Issue using a list of Booleans to index in R

Tags: r, indexing, boolean

I've had experience programming for a few years, but am relatively new to R. I ran into an unexpected result when trying to extract an entry from an array using an array of Boolean entries:

```
array = c(2, 3, 4, 5);
array[c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)]
#output: [1] 5
array[c(0, 0, 0, 1)]
#output: [1] 2
```

This surprised me, since I thought FALSE and 0 were interchangeable (likewise for TRUE and 1) in this sort of process. I checked the following to make sure, and became even more confused:

```
T==1
#output: [1] TRUE
F==0
#output: [1] TRUE
c(0,0,0,1)==c(F,F,F,T)
#output: [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Can someone help explain why R is treating these indexing methods differently?

Much thanks,

Comment: Logical and numeric values are not equivalent, it's just that for some operations (e.g. `==` when the other argument is numeric) logical values are coerced to numeric. `2` is the first element of `array`, which is why it's returned for the second subset operation (and there is no 0th element). If you want to use `0`s and `1`s to subset that way, just pass them to `as.logical` first.

Comment: If I'm hoping to index using a numeric Boolean vector, is there a best practice? I hope there's a better method than my current solution: `sum(array*array_index)` where `array_index = c(0, 0, 0, 1)`.

Comment: `vector[as.logical(numeric_vector_of_0s_and_1s)]` will work

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Nice answer! Care to post it as one? I haven't been able to find a duplicate of this, so it'd be good to have an answered question for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as.logical(c(0,0,0,1))==c(F,F,F,T)

#### Explanation

In `R`, `numeric` values are treated differently than the `logical` values.

In your scenario, Since `2` is the first element of the array, it is returned for the second subset operation (and there is no 0th element).

PS
Only for a few operations(e.g `==`), logical values are first coerced to numeric. Thanks to @IceCreamTouchan to add this in the comments above.